# Is "блестеть" or "блистать" used in the figurative "он не блещет умом"?

Tags: глаголы

> он не **блещет** умом
>
> она **блещет** красотой

Is "блестеть" or "блистать" used, when it comes to the figurative use of these verbs?

Also: Is it less common to use another form of their third-person singular "блестит/блистает"?

At least, the figurative "блестяще" comes from "блестеть".

Answer (score 3):

First of all some examples from ruscorpora.ru.

> И сердца жизнь живая, 
>   И чувства огнь святой, 
>   И дева молодая
>   *Блистает красотой*! 
>   [А. В. Кольцов. Из Горация (1841.
>
> Друзья, для нас природа
>   И в ужасах своих *блистает красотой*! 
>   [В. Л. Пушкин. К любимцам муз (1804)]
>
> Камер-фрейлине Ее Императорского Величества Авроре уже под 30 лет, но она по-прежнему *блистает красотой*, и ее замечает один из богатейших людей России Павел Демидов. [Юрий Безелянский. (1995)

**Блещет красотой**, **умом** is a set expression but the form **блистает красотой**, **блистать на сцене** is still valid, especially in the world of theatre.

The infinitive is evidently **блистать**, though the forms блещу, блещешь, блещет, блещете, блещут belong to **both infinitives** (блестеть и блистать см. Орфографический словарь ) but in this particular meaning it is *not* блестеть.

> Бог с ней, с эстетикой, мужик и не обязан *блистать красотой*. [Варвара Синицына. Муза и генерал (2002)]
>
> Точно будто родители, приносившие множество тяжелых жертв ради ее увеселения, виноваты в том, что ей нельзя *блистать красотой* в более людном месте и полонять сердца блестящих кавалеров. [П. И. Чайковский. Письма Н. Ф. фон-Мекк (1881)]
>
> Судя по его словам, Сумароков очень, любил *блистать умом* и говорить остроты, которые нынче, вероятно, не казались бы остротами, и любил умничать, что тогда принималось за ум, а ныне было бы очень скучно; например, однажды за столом у моего деда подали кулебяку. [М. А. Дмитриев. Мелочи из запаса моей памяти (1869)]
>
> Она сказала себе: «Если не могу быть прекрасною и любимою, не могу привлекать к себе взоры и сердца, то буду *блистать умом* и заставлю себя заметить и уважить везде за мои нравственные превосходства!» [Е. П. Ростопчина. Счастливая женщина (1851)]
>
> Не знаю; но сие желание *блистать умом*, или казаться глубокомысленным, едва ли не противно истинному вкусу. [Н. М. Карамзин. История государства Российского: Том 1 (1803-1818)]

Though in everyday life you should use **блещет**, but if you need an infinitive, use **блистать**, still in literature and in the world of arts you can find **блистает** as well.

Answer (score 0):

The infinitive here is definitely `блестеть`. And it will sound awkward if you say «Он не блестит умом».

**«Он не блещет умом»** is a set and wide-known expression, so the verb in it cannot be easily replaced.